# If a closed set does not separate $\mathbb{R}^n$, can one of its connected components separate $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Suppose $F$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n>1$. If the complement $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F$ of $F$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected, can we say that the complement of each connected component of $F$ is connected?

Context: In some Runge type extension theorem, we have a compact set $F$ and a function $f$ that has some regularity on a neighborhood of $F$. We want to extend $f$ to the whole space $\mathbb{R}^n$. The important condition is that $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F$ be connected. This is why it is interesting to ask questions like the one here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, suppose $X$ is any connected space and $F\subseteq X$ is a closed subset such that $X\setminus F$ is connected.  Then I claim that for any connected component $C$ of $F$, $X\setminus C$ is connected.  To prove this, suppose $X\setminus C$ were disconnected, so it is a disjoint union of two nonempty open subsets $U$ and $V$ (which are also open in $X$ since $C$ is closed in $X$).  Since $X\setminus F$ is connected, it is completely contained in one of $U$ and $V$; let us say $X\setminus F\subseteq U$.  Then $V\subseteq F$ and thus $C\cup V$ is disconnected since $C$ is a connected component of $F$.  So, we can write $C\cup V$ as a disjoint union of two nonempty closed subsets $A$ and $B$.  Since $C$ is connected, it is contained in one of $A$ and $B$; say $C\subseteq A$, so $B\subseteq V$.  Then I claim $B$ is clopen in $X$, contradicting the assumption that $X$ was connected.  First, $A$ and $B$ are both closed in $X$ since they are closed in $C\cup V$ and $C\cup V=X\setminus U$ is closed in $X$.  Then $B$ is also open in $X$ since its complement is $(X\setminus V)\cup A$, a union of two closed subsets of $X$.

Comment: Thanks. But can you please explain why $V\subset F$ and then$C\cup V$ is disconnected?

Comment: $V\subseteq F$ since $X\setminus F\subseteq U$ and $U$ and $V$ are disjoint.  $C\cup V$ is disconnected because it is a subset of $F$ that is strictly larger than $C$.